# How to add the function to change the colour of a cell on numbers after a certain date has been passed

Tags: mac, numbers

I am using Numbers on Mac and I am trying to get cells to change colour once a date has been passed, this is to keep track of warranty's of certain products, I want the cells to be green while the date in the cell is a future date and then change the red once the date in the cell has passed the current date.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for **Conditional Highlighting**.

- Select the cells that contain your date values.
- In the **Inspector** select the **Cell** tab
- With all the cells still selected, click the **Conditional Highlighting...** button.
- You will select **Add a Rule...**
- Add rule *Date is before...* Date is before the date 1 days ago | Red Fill.
- Add rule *Date is after...* Date is after the date 0 days from now | Green Fill.

Experiment with custom styles to get the look you want.  This could also be expanded with additional rules to fine tune.  For example changing the colour to Yellow if the warranty expires in the next 2 months.

For further information on how to use **Conditional Formatting** check out [Apple's Support Documentation.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17079?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

---

[image: Table with cells formatted to show dates past and future]
[image: Conditional Formatting Rules]